# change MD5 password to bcrypt password on login

Tags: php, codeigniter, passwords, md5, bcrypt

I am rewriting my procedural coded system into CodeIgniter 3 and need to convert the existing MD5 passwords to bcrypt passwords.
I have two password columns in my Db. Password_old containing the MD5 passwords, and Password (For the **to be created** bcrypt password) set as NULL default.

When a user login, the system check to see if bcrypt Password column is NULL, then check and verify the MD5 Password_old column. If successful, the system must create the bcrypt password and update the Db's Password column, then accept login...

My problem is that the login fail and I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

My Controller:

```
public function login() {

    // create the data object
    $data = new stdClass();

    // load form helper and validation library
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    // set validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Username', 'Username', 'required|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

        // validation not ok, send validation errors to the view
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('user/login/login');
        $this->load->view('footer');

    } else {

        // set variables from the form
        $username = $this->input->post('Username');
        $password = $this->input->post('Password');

        if ($this->user_model->resolve_user_login($username, $password)) {

            $user_id = $this->user_model->get_user_id_from_username($username);
    if($updatepass==1){
      $data = array(
            'Password'   => $this->user_model->hash_password($password)
          );
      $this->db->where('id', $user_id); // check where to put 
      $this->db->update('Users', $data); 
    }

    $user    = $this->user_model->get_user($user_id);

            // set session user datas
            $_SESSION['user_id']      = (int)$user->id;
            $_SESSION['username']     = (string)$user->Username;
    $_SESSION['u_email']     = (string)$user->Email;
            $_SESSION['logged_in']    = (bool)true;
            $_SESSION['is_confirmed'] = (bool)$user->is_confirmed;
            $_SESSION['is_admin']     = (bool)$user->is_admin;


            // user login ok
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('user/login/login_success', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');

        } else {

            // login failed
            $data->error = 'Wrong username or password.';

            // send error to the view
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('user/login/login', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');

        }

    }

}
```

The model I use is as follow:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * User_model class.
 * 
 * @extends CI_Model
 */
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    /**
     * __construct function.
     * 
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();

    }

    /**
     * create_user function.
     * 
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $username
     * @param mixed $email
     * @param mixed $password
     * @return bool true on success, false on failure
     */
    public function create_user($username, $email, $password) {

        $data = array(
            'Username'   => $username,
            'Email'      => $email,
            'Password'   => $this->hash_password($password),
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-j H:i:s'),
        );

        return $this->db->insert('Users', $data);

    }

    /**
     * resolve_user_login function.
     * 
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $username
     * @param mixed $password
     * @return bool true on success, false on failure
     */
    public function resolve_user_login($username, $password) {

    if((strstr($username , "@")) && (strstr($username , "."))){
    $whatus="Email='$username'";
    }else{
    $whatus="Username='$username'";
    }
        $this->db->select('Password');
        $this->db->from('Users');
        $this->db->where($whatus);
        $hash = $this->db->get()->row('Password');
    if($hash==NULL){
    $this->db->select('Password_old');
        $this->db->from('Users');
        $this->db->where($whatus);
    $hash_md5 = $this->db->get()->row('Password_old');
    $updatepass=1;
    return $this->verify_password_md5($password, $hash_md5);
    }else{
    return $this->verify_password_hash($password, $hash);
    $updatepass=0;
    }

    }
    /**
     * hash_password function.
     * 
     * @access private
     * @param mixed $password
     * @return string|bool could be a string on success, or bool false on failure
     */
    private function hash_password($password) {

        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    }

    /**
     * verify_password_hash function.
     * 
     * @access private
     * @param mixed $password
     * @param mixed $hash
     * @return bool
     */
    private function verify_password_hash($password, $hash) {

        return password_verify($password, $hash);

    }

    /**
     * verify_password_md5 function.
     * 
     * @access private
     * @param mixed $password
     * @param mixed $hash
     * @return bool
     */
    private function verify_password_md5($password, $hash_md5) {

        return password_verify($password, md5($hash_md5));

    }   
    /**
     * get_user_id_from_username function.
     * 
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $username
     * @return int the user id
     */
    public function get_user_id_from_username($username) {
    if((strstr($username , "@")) && (strstr($username , "."))){
    $whatus="Email='$username'";
    }else{
    $whatus="Username='$username'";
    }       
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->from('Users');
        $this->db->where($whatus);

        return $this->db->get()->row('id');

    }

    /**
     * get_user function.
     * 
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $user_id
     * @return object the user object
     */
    public function get_user($user_id) {

        $this->db->from('Users');
        $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
        return $this->db->get()->row();

    }

}
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries.  Also the updatepass variable is unused.  Anyway,  the login fails under what context? Old account? New account? Migrated account? Does it produce any errors or warnings?

Comment: Its a current account where I am trying to read the old MD5 Password, validate and update the new password. No errors in the log ;-(

Comment: Was 'password_hash' used to create the old MD5 hash? If not, could it be different from the old 'crypt' style generation?

Comment: The old password was originally created with $password = md5(trim($_POST['password']));

Comment: Then use that in the new legacy-login code. verify_password normally operates with a salt; I do not know if it requires it.